# Missing (system) assembly references on new project

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Using VS2015, if I create a new blank project, I get missing assembly reference errors, as shown below:

[image]

I haven't touched anything from the initial setup. I can't figure out what's wrong?

Comment: screenshot of all 19 errors may be helpful to find or fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run `dnu restore` as my dnvm versions were out of alignment.

It's something I really struggle with: I get really confused by all the places where a dnx version needs to be set. Wish MS could make it simpler and/or provide a simple guide/explanation.

Comment: Usually this is done automatically, but VS2015 is very buggy, so sometimes it faile. Alternatevly, you could call "Restore packages" from context menu for "References" item. Also sometimes you need to run dnu restore for each project in solution separately, and for each wrapped project too